# Canvas drawables and centered zooming

Tags: android, view, touch, scaling, android-canvas

I'm playing with a [Google tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) to implement zooming capabilities to my canvas.  I'm drawing several items onthe canvas and I'm able to move it via `Canvas.translate(dx,dy)` along with the items.  In order for me to determine if these items are touched after the canvas translation, I take the canvas offset used for `Canvas.translate(dx,dy)` and subtract the touch position.  Once I introduce scaling into the picture, it get's a little tricky.  If I use `Canvas.scale(sx,sy)` and do `(touchX-offsetX)/scaleFactor` the translation of the touch position after the scale works perfect.  However, if include a pivot position `Canvas.scale(sx,sy,px,py)` the code above those not work.  How do I go about factoring in the  pivot position as a part of my touch translation? I set my pivot position by doing the following,

```
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    mScaleX = detector.getFocusX();
    mScaleY = detector.getFocusY();
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
 public class ScalableImageView extends View {
    Matrix drawMatrix = new Matrix();
    ScaleGestureDetector detector;
    public ScalableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
         @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            drawMatrix.postScale(detector.getScaleFactor(), detector.getScaleFactor(), detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return drawMatrix != null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(drawMatrix);
        // ... draw here
        // for example drawable.draw()
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```

}